# Compare returned difference of fields with a variable in django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-1.5

I am trying to list all objects of a model based on the difference of field values and a variable. For example I am trying to pull objects which has been created since 3 days or more. So I am trying to query the models as follows

```
import datetime
from myapp_books.models import Book
from django.db.models import F

current_date = datetime.date.today()
books = Book.objects.annotate(day_difference=F('date_added__date') - current_date).filter(day_difference__gte=3)
books.count()
```

This is giving me an error when I run it in the shell as follows

```
AttributeError: 'ExpressionNode' object has no attribute 'lookup'
```

Please advice. I am using django 1.5.12

Comment: Django 1.5.12, but why?

Comment: F expressions only came about django 1.8+ methinks

Comment: @MosesKoledoye upgrading it requires a lot of code review, hence we have been using the same version since a while. Needs an upgrade soon.

Comment: @e4c5 I am able to import F without any issues

Comment: oops sorry  my bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need the annotation at all, you should just be able to filter on the date added that is older than 3 days old

```
Book.objects.filter(date_added__date__gte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=3))
```

<sub>Also, you should upgrade to a supported version of django</sub>

Comment: + for the bit about upgrading